# How to give Priority to Finish Build Trigger rather than VCS trigger in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity-9.0, build-triggers

I'm Using TeamCity 9.0.3 for my .net Projects in TFS Soure Code . We have Build Projects each dependent on another. Lets say Build A, B, C, D & E. and I had Setup two Triggers Finish Build Trigger and VCS Trigger for all Projects and also dependencies.

If there is a VCS change in Build C its checking for Dependencies for Build B and C for a Suitable One and then Triggering the Downstream Projects D & E. But in Between if any Devreloper Check-in done then the build Chain is Totally Screwed up.

What I exactly need is if a Build is Running with Finish build trigger, the Build Triggered with VCS Trigger Should wait untill the first Build chain is Completed.

Is there any Priority to set like that?

Comment: Can you describe in more details scenario when the build chain is screwed up?